# CSS grid: two columns, unless smaller than 150px

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid riddle, which seems to be simple, but I just have no idea and two AI chats failed as well.
I have this:

```css
.cont {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(150px, 100%), 1fr));
 }
.box {background-color: grey;}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="box">one</div>
<div class="box">two</div>
<div class="box">three</div>
<div class="box">four</div>
</div>
```

What I need, is for the boxes to always be full available width and in two (and only two) columns, unless the screen gets too small and the box would get smaller than 150px, in which case switch to one column. Without the use of media queries.
The written rule "grid-template-columns" is just one of the things I tried, it's a classic (got from Kevin Powell) that's great, if you allow for any number of columns on wider display.
If you can achieve the same with flex, I guess that's fine too.

Comment: Why without the use of media queries? Use JS than to trigger class change on certain screen width

Comment: Well, it's more of a challenge to do it smarter and with less lines. Just like the rule for grid-template-columns in the example is awesome for eshop products without using media queries, then I am trying to achieve something similar, basically with additional limitations. It's not necessary, but it would be really nice to find some clever hack.

Comment: Smarter would be to use css the way it was intended instead of creating a hacky solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `max()` not `min()` and a value that is a little bigger than `100%/3` to make sure you have less than 3 items per row (so 2 items)

```css
.cont {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max(150px, 34%), 1fr));
 }
.box {background-color: grey;}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="box">one</div>
<div class="box">two</div>
<div class="box">three</div>
<div class="box">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another great solution. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using flexbox:

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 10px);
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="box">one</div>
  <div class="box">two</div>
  <div class="box">three</div>
  <div class="box">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost there, but doesn't stretch the boxes to full width, when in single-column mode.

Comment: @maeros updated to use flexbox instead.

Comment: Nice! good job, thanks :-)